# TreeMap Force Close

Tags: android, linked-list, treemap

I am new to TreeMap.

I have tried the following code:

```
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : MultiSelect_TreeMap.entrySet()) {
        int Books = entry.getValue();

        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry2 : MultiSelect_TreeMap2.entrySet()) {
            int CalculatedBooks = entry2.getKey();
            int Books2 = entry2.getValue();
            int Pages = CalculatedBooks - (BooksPos * MaxPos);
            MySQLITE_DATABASE.DeleteIfExist(Books, Pages);
            if(Books == Books2) 
            {
                MultiSelect_LinkedList.add(Pages);
                MultiSelect_TreeMap.remove(CalculatedBooks);
                MultiSelect_TreeMap2.remove(CalculatedBooks);
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the force close error:

LogCat:

```
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at java.util.TreeMap$MapIterator.stepForward(TreeMap.java:883)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at java.util.TreeMap$EntrySet$1.next(TreeMap.java:924)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at java.util.TreeMap$EntrySet$1.next(TreeMap.java:922)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at test.project.MainActivity.DeleteAllSelectedNames(MainActivity.java:1012)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at test.project.MainActivity$15.onClick(MainActivity.java:1274)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-20 08:15:54.220: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you modify the content of the map while you are fast enumerating it. you are not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for each loop cannot remove items from the underlying collection. You can either count indeces manually

```
for(int i = 0; i < MultiSelect_TreeMap.size(); i++){
//...
}
```

or use the iterator

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = MultiSelect_TreeMap.entrySet().iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
    //...
    if (condition) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I guessed, what your usecase actually could be. The following code will remove entries from both maps, if there is an Entry in mapA, that is equal to an entry in mapB.

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer,Integer>> it = mapA.entrySet().iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
    Entry<Integer,Integer> entry = it.next();

    Integer calcBooks = entry.getKey();
    Integer books1 = entry.getValue();

    if(mapB.containsKey(calcBooks)){

        Integer books2 = mapB.get(calcBooks);

        if(books1.equals(books2)){
            mapB.remove(entry);
            it.remove();
        }
    }               
}
```

**EDIT2:** The class cast error isn't directly related to the first problem. The treemap organizes the order of elements by comparison. Therefore, the tree needs a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29) for its elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  I have tried the code, but it gave me "TreeMap$Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable" force close.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry I've been very busy.  it was my TreeMap issues.  It worked.  Once again, thank you very much for the help.